# How to draw a line() in processing.js?

Tags: javascript, html, processing, line

Today I was learning about some shapes in processing like ellipse, line, rect. When I actually tried to code it, it didn't drew any line or ellipse. Here is the code

```
<! doctype html>
<html>
<!-- styles, title, head, etc -->
<body>
  <canvas id='cvs'></canvas>
  <script type='text/processing' data-processing-target='cvs' src='processing.js'>
  // The processing.js and html(this) file are both on my desktop
    size(400, 400);
    line(100, 100, 300, 300);
    ellipse(200, 200, 100, 100);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Btw, I was learning on Khan academy.

Comment: can you post screen shot of your output?

Comment: I tried but the scrShot is bigger than 2Mb. The output was only a greyish window, and nothing else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like something isn't loading properly. Please take a look at your [developer tools](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/javascript/developer-tools) for any errors or files that aren't loading properly.

One thing that jumps out at me is you probably want to put your code inside a `setup()` and `draw()` function, like this:

```
void setup(){
 size(400, 400);
}

void draw(){
  line(100, 100, 300, 300);
  ellipse(200, 200, 100, 100);
}
```

If you still can't get it figured out, then please post a link to a JSFiddle or CodePen that we can play with.

Comment: Thanks for your help!
My script src was incorrect. Btw, how could I make the size fit the whole screen

Comment: @Blue Please ask follow-up questions in their own posts, but please do some googling first. Try searching for "processing.js fullscreen" for a ton of results. Good luck.